# Member function of a class as friend to another class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, forward-declaration, friend-function

In this code , i have made max function of class B friend of class A.I have also done forward declaration of class B.But it is giving error.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
   int a;
   public:

   void get()
   {
      cin>>a;
   }

   friend void B :: max(A , B);
};

class B
{
   int b;
   public:

   void get()
   {
      cin>>b;
   }

   void max(A x, B y)
   {
      if (x.a > y.b)
         cout<< " x is greater";
      else cout<<"y is greater";
   }
};

int main()
{
   A x;
   B y,c;
   x.get();
   y.get();
   c.max(x,y);
}
```

Comment: **Always** post any error text your questioning **verbatim**.

Comment: Did you see this question in your research: [Declare a member-function of a forward-declared class as friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310720/declare-a-member-function-of-a-forward-declared-class-as-friend)

Comment: You can get some tips here: [How to forward declare a member function of a class to use in another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344195/how-to-forward-declare-a-member-function-of-a-class-to-use-in-another-class?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` is incomplete at the point where you declare `B::max` as a friend method. Thus, compiler does not know if there is such a method.

This means that you need to

1. reorder classes, so that `A` knows `B` has a method `B::max` and
2. Implement the method `B::max` outside of the class definition, when both classes are complete, because you access internal variables.

It is also a good idea to pass your arguments by const reference. Use `const` to emphasise that you are not modifying them. Pass by reference to avoid unnecessary copying.

So, with this in mind:

```
class A;

class B{
    int b;
public: 
    void get(){
        cin>>b;
    }
    void max(const A& x, const B& y);
};

class A{
    int a;
public:
    void get(){
        cin>>a;
    }
    friend void B :: max(const A& , const B&);
};

void B::max(const A& x, const B& y) {
    if (x.a > y.b)
       cout<< " x is greater";
    else
        cout<<"y is greater";
}
```

Comment: Tweaked the answer to correct myself, that point was not necessary

Answer (score 2):

As **R Sahu** already answered:

You cannot use:

```
friend void B :: max(A , B);
```

without the complete definition of B.

This is how you can achieve your goal:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A;

class B{
    int b = 2;

public: 
    void max(A x, B y);
};

class A{
    int a = 1;
public:
    friend void B :: max(A , B);
};

void B::max(A x, B y){
    if (x.a > y.b)
        cout<< " x is greater";
    else 
        cout<<"y is greater";
}

int main(){
A x;
B y,c;
c.max(x,y);
}
```

Comment: was about to answer just that :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use:

```
friend void B :: max(A , B);
```

without the complete definition of `B`.

You'll need to rethink your strategy so that you can implement the functionality without using the `friend` declaration or move the definition of `B` ahead of the definition of `A`.

Comment: Pls tell me how i can do that.

Comment: You could just `friend class B`, if you have no problem friending the entire class.

Comment: can i declare  void B:: max(A,B); after forward declaration of class B;

Comment: @ishanbansal, no, you can't do that.